# Make it as Web Link

Tags: html, .net, email, hyperlink

my problem is here,

```
"<html><body> " + BodyHeader + " <br/><br/>" + Bodycontent + "<br/><br/>" + gg + "<br/><br/>" + "Please log into TMS in order to review the timesheet. Access TMS at : http://tms.example.com "+  "<br/><br/>" + BodyFooter + "<br/><br/></body></html>";
```

I am converting DataTable to HTML table to send Email to Users. I mentioned some link also. This link is just displaying as text in yahoo mail, but in gmail and other mail systems am getting this as link. I want to show as link in Yahoo also. Help me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the url in an "`<a></a>`" tag as some email clients won't automatically convert urls to links:

```
<a href='http://tms.example.com'>http://tms.example.com</a>
```